# Происхождение слова "сугубо"

Tags: этимология

Единственное, что мне удалось найти:

Происходит от др.-русск. сугубъ, сугубь, ст.-слав. соугоубь (др.-греч. διττός, διπλοῦς; Клоц., Супр., Еuсh. Sin.). По-видимому, из *sǫ- (см. су- I) и к.* gub-; родств. гибкий, губить, гнуть. Ст.-слав. соу- вместо *сѫ-, возм., объясняется ассимиляцией гласных. Ср. др.-прусск. dwigubbus "двойной", лит. dvìgubas.

Но я совсем не понимаю как это относится к современному значению слова. Может, есть какие-нибудь другие версии?

Answer (score 3):

Не опираясь на авторитетные источники, выскажу свое мнение. Что означает выражение, например, "сугубо положительное мнение"? Это означает, что нет абсолютно никаких негативных моментов, нюансов и так далее, сиречь нет какого-то изгиба в неположительную сторону – все ровно, устойчиво. То есть сугубо – это буквально "без изгибов, отклонений".

Есть вторая версия, которая мне кажется более правдоподобной. Еще одно значение "сугубо" – это "дважды, два, вдвойне, вдвое" (или "двояко", зависит от контекста: сугубосотный – двухсотный, сугубобытный – двоякий). Есть еще слово "трегубо" – "втройне", "троекратно". Тогда "сугубо" в вышеприведенном примере ("сугубо положительное мнение") – это усилительный прием (ср. "Ты дважды прав!"). Или может иметься "следующий уровень". Например, есть гриф "секретно", а есть "совершенно секретно". Последнее можно заменить на "сугубо секретно" (дважды секретно, второй уровень секретности).

Comment: Сугубо-согнуто-сложено вдвое-вдвойне - видимо так.
Мне кажется вторая версия это и есть правильный ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Прошло много лет и я понял, что оба ответа одинаково имеют смысл. Да, они разные. Но их единство можно выразить как "совершено", "абсолютно", "исключительно". Возможно, это истина найденного противоречия и развитие смысла слова "сугубо".

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/40930)